# Rails many-one relationship for Servers and Disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have models Disk and Server. Here more than one Server going to share same Disk. I want to make relationship between Disk and Server. If I use following it becomes meaningless because disk cannot have servers and server have disks.

```
Class Server < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :disk
end

Class Disk < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :servers
end
```

How do I do to make relationship between Server and Disk so that more than one Server share the same disk ?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about why this is useless ?

Comment: You can use many to many relation ship. Has many through association.

Comment: @sajan: I mentioned it's meaningless because disk is part of server(computer machine) and reverse is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) to set this relationship up, using a `disks_servers` join table which can be created using a migration:

```
class CreateDisksServersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :disks, :servers
  end
end
```

Then your models need to reference each other with `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
Class Server < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :disks
end

Class Disk < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :servers
end
```

I'm assuming here that your `ApplicationRecord` class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Model`. If it doesn't then this will probably not work!

Comment: ApplicationRecord is introduced in Rails 5, which does indeed inherit from `ActiveRecord::Model`. Rails 5 generates that model for you so you can customise ApplicationRecord instead of monkey patching ActiveRecord::Base.